# prevent page from scroll up in asp.net link button

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

how can I prevent page from scroll up after user click link button I have update panale warp my form I try to user on OnClientClick="return false" but no use
even I try this Javascript function

```
window.scrollTo = function (x, y) {
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `.Focus()` server-side method. E.g. if your LinkButton is called LinkButton1, add this to your Linkbutton's Click event handler:

```
LinkButton1.Focus();
```

Comment: What do you mean? Internally it generates relevant JS to focus on your element

Comment: it is style issue i inform our design to take care of this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack` property to `false` ([MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback.aspx)). If that doesn't work, take a look at this [script for maintaining scroll position for async postbacks](http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewfrederick/archive/2008/03/04/maintain-scroll-position-after-asynchronous-postback.aspx).